# Exporting FBX file does not show Mix Shader

Tags: materials, shaders, .fbx, shader-nodes

The FBX file that I export does not show Mix Shader and some material in Microsoft 3D Viewer. I found an explanation about exporting Shader and the explanation told us to use Principled BSDF to fully export all of the shader and material but I do not know the way of using the Principled BSDF and seeking help in exporting it and display it in Microsoft 3D Viewer.

Thank you in advance for the help. Newcomer here any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can't export the shader configuration to fbx, only the textures. The author probably meant the Principled BSDF will export all the texture images.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: @FFeller if i wanted to export all of the shader and material which export file should i use to get the most out of it?

Comment: The shaders are software specific. Probably the best you can do is packiging the texture files.